# Add things to the application menu in a Chrome app

Tags: menu, google-chrome-app

Is it possible to add items to the application window (as opposed to the context menu) in a Chrome app? (Or, for that matter, alter it in any way?)

Comment: Have you tried using `contextMenus` API with the context `launcher`? Quote: _"The 'launcher' context is only supported by apps and is used to add menu items to the context menu that appears when clicking on the app icon in the launcher/taskbar/dock/etc."_

Comment: I just did, and no dice (on Mac)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No. This menu is not part of the Chrome App execution environment. On some platforms (e.g., Chrome OS) it doesn't even exist. Where you see it, it's because the app wrapper for that particular OS supplies it automatically. Instead, use context menus, buttons and other controls, or, if you like, your own menu bar.